# Retrieving data from class with polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to create a hotel room control system and am trying to implement the OOP to handle the different types of rooms.

This is the parent class called `HotelRoom`:

```
class HotelRoom{
public:
    HotelRoom(int room_number, double cost_per_night){
        room_number = room_number;
        cost_per_night = cost_per_night;
    };

    int get_room_number(){
        return room_number;
    };

    void set_room_number(int new_room_number){
        room_number = new_room_number;
    };

    double get_cost_per_night(){
        return cost_per_night;
    };

    void set_cost_per_night(double cost_per_night){
        cost_per_night = cost_per_night;
    };

    Date get_last_checkin(){
        return last_checkin;
    };

    void set_last_checkin(Date date_checked){
        last_checkin = date_checked;
    };

    bool get_booked(){
        return booked;
    };

    void set_get_booked(bool booked){
        booked = booked;
    };

private:
    int room_number;
    double cost_per_night;
    Date last_checkin;
    bool booked = false;
};
```

And this is the child class called `SingleRoom`:

```
class SingleRoom: public HotelRoom{
public:

    SingleRoom(int room_number, double cost_per_night, string bed_size):HotelRoom(room_number, cost_per_night){
        bed_size = bed_size;
    };

    void set_bed_size(string bed_size){
        bed_size = bed_size;
    }

    string get_bed_size(){
        return bed_size;
    };

private:
    string bed_size;
};
```

And this is the main function:

```
int main(){

    SingleRoom new_room(123, 43.22, "Large");
    cout<<new_room.get_room_number()<<endl;

}
```

When I run this code, I expect the room number 123 to print out, however I get a large negative number. Maybe a memory location?

Not sure where its going wrong and appreciate any help!

Comment: `room_number = room_number;` has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to `this` or changing the name of the parameters (like in @KarstenKoop's answer) is using a member initializer list (as @melpomene mentions), like this:

```
HotelRoom(int room_number, double cost_per_night)
    : room_number(room_number), cost_per_night(cost_per_night)
{
}
```

By the way, no need for `;` after defining functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help - your solution works!. I know I dont have to use a ```;``` after defining functions I just do it for consistency. Is this bad practise?

Comment: It does not really matter, although it may be a bit strange for other programmers, since it is not common :) Also, note that in `SingleRoom::set_bed_size` you didn't use it!

Comment: Will be using it at later points in the program :) Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor

```
HotelRoom(int room_number, double cost_per_night){
    room_number = room_number;
    cost_per_night = cost_per_night;
};
```

you are assigning the value of the parameter `room_number` to itself. Replace this with

```
this->room_number = room_number;
```

or name your member variable differently. Same with `cost_per_night`.

Comment: Or use a member initializer list.